# Problem converting stock market data to time series

Tags: r, dataframe, time, time-series, stock

I have the following dataset that I imported with this code

SP  <- read.csv("https://www.six-group.com/exchanges/downloads/indexdata/hnsidpr.csv",sep = ";", skip = 4)

DATE  Close Close.1 Close.2 Close.3 Close.4 Close.5 Close.6 Close.7
1  18.02.2022 172.22    1000 3829.77 1955.40 4001.37 2014.01 1280.79 1011.82
2  17.02.2022 173.20    1000 3878.00 1983.29 3988.02 2030.51 1310.90 1004.82
3  16.02.2022 174.76    1000 3889.62 2003.20 3996.80 2052.73 1330.41 1007.40
4  15.02.2022 174.69    1000 3866.08 2007.90 4015.36 2040.00 1338.31 1008.88
5  14.02.2022 172.45    1000 3780.49 1963.68 3986.77 2008.06 1306.15 1009.98
6  11.02.2022 175.46    1000 3878.86 2003.43 4048.14 2036.01 1338.99 1013.67
7  10.02.2022 176.61    1000 3909.47 2036.39 4022.47 2065.25 1360.41 1005.19
8  09.02.2022 177.12    1000 3877.06 2030.96 4051.55 2069.34 1353.31 1004.45
9  08.02.2022 174.02    1000 3842.08 1991.77 3990.61 2030.26 1325.81 1002.24
10 07.02.2022 174.89    1000 3951.79 2013.80 4025.02 2038.04 1314.56  995.97

I need to transform it to time series to get the normal return. I have used two codes.

SP <- xts(SP, order.by = dmy(SP[,1]))

I got the time series dataset but I have the column of date two times.

With this one
SP<- xts(SP, order.by = SP[,1])

I got the error order.by requires an appropriate time-based object

Someone could hive me a hand. Thanks

Comment: Hi, Sebastian  and welcome to SO. From what library is `xts`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `read.zoo` to create a zoo series and then convert it to xts.

```
library(xts)
u <- "https://www.six-group.com/exchanges/downloads/indexdata/hnsidpr.csv"
z <- read.zoo(u, header = TRUE, sep = ";", skip = 4, format = "%d.%m.%Y")
x <- as.xts(z)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling a lot! You were really helpful, thanks again.